# MongoDB: big size of mapped memory

Tags: linux, mongodb, memory, memory-management

I use Mongo 2.4.9 and I have a replica sets for three nodes.
I have performed db.serverStatus().mem and see that size of mapped is very high, 47GB:

```
db.serverStatus().mem
{
        "bits" : 64,
        "resident" : 266,
        "virtual" : 10149,
        "supported" : true,
        "mapped" : 47402,
        "mappedWithJournal" : 65730
}
```

Result of db.stats(1024)

```
{
        "db" : "xxxxx",
        "collections" : 7,
        "objects" : 670488,
        "avgObjSize" : 2890.6140721385023,
        "dataSize" : 1892697,
        "storageSize" : 2273304,
        "numExtents" : 49,
        "indexes" : 42,
        "indexSize" : 399378,
        "fileSize" : 10416128,
        "nsSizeMB" : 16,
        "dataFileVersion" : {
                "major" : 4,
                "minor" : 5
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

In megabytes

```
"dataSize" : 1848mb
"storageSize" : 2220mb
"fileSize" : 10172mb
```

WorkingSet info:

```
"workingSet" : {
         "note" : "thisIsAnEstimate",
         "pagesInMemory" : 152599,
         "computationTimeMicros" : 31143,
         "overSeconds" : 1728
 }
```

Size(Mb) = 152599*4kb -> convert to Mb = 596 Mb

My question is why the size of mapped memory is 4,2 times greater than fileSize and 15159 times greater than the storageSize or dataSize ?
Mapped memory memory continues to grow slowly.

Note:
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 (Tikanga)
Physical memory: 3892Mb

I read this [article](http://www.polyspot.com/en/blog/2012/understanding-mongodb-storage/) but still don't understand why the size of mapped memory so large taking into account the enough small size of real data (filesize).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many databases do you have on your mongo instance? The thing is `serverStatus` provides instance info taking into account all databases it has, regarding `mapped` field:

> The value of mapped provides the amount of mapped memory, in megabytes
>   (MB), by the database. Because MongoDB uses memory-mapped files, this
>   value is likely to be to be roughly equivalent to the total size of
>   your database **or databases**.

While db.stats:

> Returns statistics that reflect the use state of a **single database**.

If there aren't any other databases on your instance take a look at the size of you `local` db. This could be quite big depending on your oplog size for the replica set.

**ANSWER TO THE COMMENT:**

Changing oplog size is not a trivial operation and it's also very important to pick a proper oplog size as it affects delayed members and replication lag. I suggest reading this article first [Change the Size of the Oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/).

You don't have to worry that the size of mapped memory exceeds your physical memory and it should not be the reason of poor query performance by itself. Mapped memory is not "real" memory allocation. It's **resident memory** that shows how much memory mongo explicitly owns in RAM.

The portion of oplog in the working set should depend on how far your secondaries are behind the master.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for quick response. You are right, the serverStatus command returns info for all databases.
I have following databases:

>show databases

27017   (empty)
admin   (empty)
config  (empty)
local   24.06640625GB
test    (empty)
myDB     9.94921875GB

the size of oplog.rs collection is 23386Mb =~23gb

Comment: I have next questions: Can I safely drop oplog collection to change init size? Whether the large size of mapped memory affects performance of an queries taking into account not large size of physical memory (mapped 32gb > physical 4gb)? Whether data form oplog coll is part of working set ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, for the update. I have tested some slow queries on my local machine (windows 7 OS) which take a lot of time on linux server, the performance is much better despite on same hardware configuration. When a query performs at the first time then free memory reduces and cached mem grows as well as resident memory. During that time I see many page falls. But after a while if were no expensive queries to server then free memory again grows and cached/resident memory decreases. when I said "for a while" I meant 3-5 minutes. I don't understand why linux os so quickly releases cached memory.

Comment: Moreover I've analyzed result of top/free commands on linux server, there are no "memory pressure" form other process. Maybe there is any way to tweak Linux to disallow release memory so quickly ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not good at Linux so I don't think I can help with tuning Lnuz memory management